# PHP Select Orders of Day From MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `order` and it has few columns like `customer`, `phone` and `orderdate` which this one has MySQL `Date` field type format and it is loaded like

```
  orderdate
-|----------|--
 |2014-06-12|
 |2014-06-13|
 |2014-06-12|
 |2014-06-14|
 |2014-06-14|
 |2014-06-11|
 |2014-06-11|
```

now I tried to get all orders of day by running a query like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM order WHERE orderdate = DATE(NOW())";
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM order WHERE DATE(orderdate) = DATE(NOW())";
```

but I am not getting any thing not even error message. Can you please let me know how I can do this? Thanks

Update:
Here is the whole code:

```
<?PHP
include 'conconfig.php';
$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
  if (mysqli_connect_error()) 
   { 
     die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
   }
 $query = "SELECT * FROM order WHERE DATE(orderdate) = DATE(NOW())";

 if ($result = $con->query($query)) 
{
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
    $resultStr.=  '<table style="width:300px">';
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {

            $resultStr.=  '<tr><td>'.$row['customer'].'</td><td>'.$row['phone'].'</td></tr>';   
        }
        $resultStr.=  '</table>';
    }
    else
    {
        $resultStr = 'There is No Order For Today';
    }
}
echo $resultStr;
$con->close();
```

Comment: That query looks fine. How are you running it? a little code will help

Comment: Hi Hanky I updated the code, can you please take alook at that?

Comment: The query looks fine.  Is there any matching data?  There isn't any in your example.

Comment: Your `$con->query` if block needs an else with `echo $con->error;`. That will tell you the reason

Comment: Maybe this answers your question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427061/how-do-i-get-mysql-results-of-todays-date

Comment: As @Hanky웃Panky said, add a `die` and `dump` to your else statement, that will show you what the error is in particular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Order` is  a reserved word. Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE orderdate = DATE(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

Order is a reserved word. You can escape it with ` like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE ...
```

Here is a list of reserved words which should be avoided as mysql table and column names.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html